# Setting sql date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't work out what has changed to only just start getting this error

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I have checked that the language of the SQL Server instance is "British English"
I have checked that the language of the user is "British English"

What have I missed?

```
select * from table where updated <= '15/09/2012'
```

If I run set dateformat dmy, it works, but obviously only at a session level.  I need to fix it for the server

Comment: See [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189491.aspx) OR use format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Do you have the option to explicitly cast your date literal?, i.e. change the SQL syntax

Comment: But why use that format and (a) not the ISO Format that alawys works or (b) use a parameter

Comment: Did you try `where updated <= '2012-09-15'`

Comment: What if you pass the date in this format - `2012-09-15`

Comment: To clarify - I don't want to change the SQL, it just needs to work...it has done until recently

Comment: If it worked "until recently" then either A) your code or system configuration changed or B) you had been extremely lucky until now. If the former, find out what changed. If the latter, **never** rely upon chance, because circumstances change easily.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach which eliminates all ambiguity is to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting for all your dates - `2012-09-15`. And that will work regardless of your regional settings.

Comment: While probably right, it's not particularly helpful - this would involve rewriting a fair bit of the code, where it just needs to work for the moment...

Comment: You can do it right, or you can do it twice. Which one is more expensive?

Comment: I'm not sure why my question itself is being brought in to question...currently, doing it twice is more expensive.  There isn't the budget available for someone to go through the codebase and replace all date instances. It's an inherited codebase, and it's not very well built

Comment: An even better option is to use parameterized queries instead of passing date literals.  That avoids the date format ugliness, is more secure, and provides performance benefits.

Comment: Because your imagined solution is merely a band-aid, and a weak one at that. You have no assurance that your proposed solution won't cause problems with **other** queries. OTOH, the ISO format suggestion (which you've gotten 4 times now) will work in all cases. **Fix the root cause** - ambiguous date interpretation.

Comment: Jeees. I'm aware there's a right way and a wrong way to do this.  The fact is, this system needs to be back up and running *now*...not in 3 weeks after we've been able to locate the source code and make all of the thousands of changes we'll need to make to bring it up to standard.  I am actually looking for the band-aid solution!

Comment: Whilst the gist of this answer is okay, unfortunately the format you've recommended can still be interpreted ambiguously if the column for comparison is a `datetime` (instead of `date` or `datetime2`). `20120915` (no separators) is unambiguous. `set language british
select DATEPART(month,CONVERT(datetime,'2014-05-07'))` returns `7` not `5`.

Answer (score 0):

**`select * from table where convert(date,updated,105) <= '15/09/2012'`**

can you check above query?. I hope it will work.

```
 declare @updated date = GetDate()

 select 
 case when (convert(date,'15/09/2012', 105) <= @updated) then 1
 else 2 end
```

this query is giving 1 as output, so i guess it would work for your case also.